# create model instance provider class in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, uml, class-diagram, ocl

how can I create model instance provider class in eclipse?

Comment: What is a model instance provider class?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse models normally exploit EMF which has the ability to generate Java from the models. An `XXXFactory` is generated and this has the ability to create instances.